# GROUP BY clause to comma-separated return

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wanting to group by days and return a comma-separated of the ids.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  Days VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Data

```
INSERT INTO data (Id, Days)
VALUES 
(2612,'4'),
(2614,'4'),
(2617,'5'),
(2651,'6'),
(2652,'7');
```

SQL

```
Select 
Ids = 
    STUFF((SELECT ',' +  CAST(b.Id AS varchar)
           FROM data b 
           WHERE b.Id = a.Id 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
from 
data a
group by Days
```

Expected result

```
Ids    
---------------------------------------------------
2612,2614
2617
2651
2652
```

Error

> (no result to output)

Sample Corrected

https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=f688372d-3952-4de9-ad10-7930a6428ee8

Comment: you can't insert into ID column cause it's identity. Remove the identity part and try again. Also, `WHERE b.Id = a.Id `should be `WHERE b.Days = a.Days`

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have? Also why do you need to store a separate table, why not use a view or a CTE?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Versions

Comment: Its a simple typo ... use `WHERE b.Id = a.Id ` as siggemannen says. https://dbfiddle.uk/DPVX5l57

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using STUFF is the old way of handling this. Using [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is much simpler and makes this faster because you don't need any joins.

```
select Ids = string_agg(Id, ',')
from Data
group by days
```

As mentioned in the comments. You can't insert identity values when identity_insert is off. Either remove the identity or set identity_insert on for that table.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am sql server 2016 I don’t believe this is included

Comment: @Jefferson have you considered upgrading? 2016 is in extended support which means it is gasping for air near the end of life. It will no longer receive any updates other than security fixes. There have been three major releases since then.

Answer (score 1):

You are correlating by the wrong column, you need to correlate by `Days`.

```sql
SELECT
  Ids = STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' +  CAST(b.Id AS varchar(12))
    FROM data d_Inner
    WHERE d_Inner.Days = d.Days 
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
FROM data d
GROUP BY
  d.Days
```

Note that if you want to aggregate text then you need to make sure to unescape  the XML correctly:

```sql
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
```